# unable to add node in treeview after selecting any item getting an error Index must be within the bounds of the List. Parameter name: index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, treeviewitem

When i am adding node in treeview after selecting any node some time its adding and some time item not adding and giving an error Index must be within the bounds of the List. Parameter name: index

Code i am following is

```
public void AddWorkflowItem()
        {
            DeletePageNoFromContentTreeView();
            string ToolTips = null;
            if (baseCase.LockUser == null)
            {
                View.ResultOperation.Message =
                    "Case has been unlocked by ACR Production Specialist. System is unable to save changes.";
                View.ResultOperation.IsSuccessfully = false;
                return;
            }
            if (baseCase.LockUser.Id != AuthenticationService.CurrentUser.Id)
            {
                View.ResultOperation.Message =
                    new StringBuilder("Case has been locked by ")
                        .Append(baseCase.LockUser.Profile.Degree + " ")
                        .Append(baseCase.LockUser.Profile.FirstName + " ")
                        .Append(baseCase.LockUser.Profile.LastName + ". System is unable to save changes.")
                        .ToString();
                View.ResultOperation.IsSuccessfully = false;
                return;
            }
            CipCaseWorkflowItem newItem = null;
            ISet<CipCaseWorkflowItem> list = GetCaseWorkflow();
            CaseContentItemType selectedItem =
                (CaseContentItemType)
                Enum.Parse(typeof(CaseContentItemType), View.AddCaseContentItemTypeList.SelectedValue);
            ContentElementType selectedTextItem = ContentElementType.None;
            switch (selectedItem)
            {
                case CaseContentItemType.BaseCaseTextElement:
                    selectedTextItem =
                        (ContentElementType)
                        Enum.Parse(typeof(ContentElementType), View.AddCaseContentSubItemTypeList.SelectedValue);
                    //GetContentElementType(View.AddCaseContentSubItemTypeList.SelectedValue);//
                    newItem = new CipTextElementScriptItem(cipCase, selectedTextItem);
                    newItem.Type = selectedItem;
                    newItem.IsEmpty = true;
                    break;
                case CaseContentItemType.TemplatedItem:
                    CaseContentTemplatedItemType selectedTemplateItem =
                        (CaseContentTemplatedItemType)
                        Enum.Parse(typeof(CaseContentTemplatedItemType),
                                   View.AddCaseContentSubItemTypeList.SelectedValue);
                    //newItem = new CipTemplatedScriptItem(cipCase, selectedTemplateItem);
                    newItem = CreateCipWorkflowTemplatedItem(cipCase, selectedTemplateItem);
                    newItem.IsEmpty = false;
                    break;
                case CaseContentItemType.Question:
                    newItem = new CipQuestionScriptItem(cipCase);
                    ((CipQuestionScriptItem)newItem).ColumnsNo = 1;
                    newItem.Type = selectedItem;
                    if (View.AddActiveView == CaseContentAddActiveView.NoQuestions)
                    {
                        newItem.IsEmpty = true;
                        ToolTips = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int questionId = Int32.Parse(View.AddQuestionList.SelectedValue);
                        QuestionElement question = FindQuestionById(questionId);
                        ((CipQuestionScriptItem)newItem).QuestionElement = question;
                        newItem.IsEmpty = false;
                        ToolTips = question.GetToolTip();
                    }
                    break;
                case CaseContentItemType.CaseCredits:
                case CaseContentItemType.PageBreak:
                case CaseContentItemType.CIPCMEGraphic:
                case CaseContentItemType.CaseAuthours:
                case CaseContentItemType.CMEInfo:
                case CaseContentItemType.PostTest:
                case CaseContentItemType.EmptyLine:
                case CaseContentItemType.HorizontalLine:
                    newItem = new CipCaseWorkflowItem(cipCase, selectedItem);
                    newItem.IsEmpty = false;
                    break;
                    case CaseContentItemType.Image:
                    newItem = new CipImageScriptItem(cipCase);
                    newItem.IsEmpty = false;                    
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid context item type.");
            }
            TreeNode selectedNode = contentTreeView.SelectedNode;
            newItem.IsHidden = false;
            //TreeNode rootNode = contentTreeView.Nodes[0];
            if ((selectedNode != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedNode.Value))
            {
                CaseContentItemType itemType;
                ContentElementType textElementType;
                CaseContentTemplatedItemType templatedItemType;
                int id;
                string nodeId = selectedNode.Value;
                ParseNodeId(nodeId, out itemType, out textElementType, out templatedItemType, out id);
                CipCaseWorkflowItem current = FindSelectedItemIdById(id);
                int newItemSortField = current.SortField + 1;
                newItem.SortField = newItemSortField;
                IncreaseSortIndex(newItemSortField);
                cipCase.WorkflowItems.Add(newItem);
            }
            else
            {
                int maxIndex;
                GetMaxIndex(list, out maxIndex);
                maxIndex++;
                newItem.SortField = maxIndex;
                cipCase.WorkflowItems.Add(newItem);
            }
            if (selectedItem != CaseContentItemType.Question)
                FindAndAttachSingleItem(selectedItem, selectedTextItem, newItem, out ToolTips);
            baseCase.LastEditedDate = DateTime.Now;
            Ioc.Resolve<IWebSessionManager>().CurrentSession.Flush();
            TreeNode newNode = CreateTreeNode(newItem, null);
            if (ToolTips != null)
                newNode.ToolTip = AddContentItemStateToToolTip(newItem.IsHidden, ToolTips);
            else
                newNode.ToolTip = AddContentItemStateToToolTip(newItem.IsHidden, string.Empty);
            if (selectedNode != null)
                contentTreeView.Nodes.AddAt(newItem.SortField, newNode);
            else
                contentTreeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
               SetWorkflowActionButtonState();
            if (selectedItem == CaseContentItemType.CaseCredits)
                SetupAddCombos();
            if (selectedItem == CaseContentItemType.Question)
                SetupSubItemCombo(selectedItem);

            DeletePageNoFromContentTreeView();
            SetupPagenumbersToContentTreeView();
            if (selectedItem == CaseContentItemType.Image)
            {
                SetupPageForSelectedNode(newNode);
                //View.AddActiveView = CaseContentAddActiveView.Images;
            }

            newNode.Select();
            SetupPageForSelectedNode(newNode);
            SetWorkflowActionButtonState();
        }
```

protected void IncreaseSortIndex(int sortIndex)
{

```
foreach (CipCaseWorkflowItem item in cipCase.WorkflowItems)
    {
        if (item.SortField >= sortIndex)
        item.SortField++;
      }
```

}

error is coming in this line

```
  if (selectedNode != null)
                contentTreeView.Nodes.AddAt(newItem.SortField, newNode);
```

Comment: Whats the value of newItem.SortField when it dies?

Comment: I am trying to add item to next node which is selected but its adding any where else...

Comment: @BugFinder: value of newItem.SortField when it dies, is incremented value to SortField, suppose Sort Filed value is 139 then newItem.SortField is 140

Comment: Please help me it this prob. i am unable to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function before the call of `DeletePageNoFromContentTreeView();`

```
    protected void ResortWorkflowItems()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (CipCaseWorkflowItem item in cipCase.WorkflowItems)
            item.SortField = i++;
        baseCase.LastEditedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Ioc.Resolve<IWebSessionManager>().CurrentSession.Flush();
    }
```